# Can I use recaptcha v3 to verify click traffic?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a website where people can interact with different objects to view specific content. I would like to know which objects get the most interactions by real people. For example there are thumbnails of images and I would like to know when a user clicks on a thumbnail to view an image.
To do this I thought I would create a psql table with thumbnail_id and an IP address, where every single view is stored (to ensure every combination of thumbnail and ip is only counted once and people can't just spam click it).
And so every time a click happens, a post request on a /views endpoint with the thumbnail id attached is made in the background.

The proplem is, some people may be incentivized to create bots to auto click certain images with many different IPs.
So I was wondering if I could use recaptcha v3 to identify real users as opposed to bots which would include a token with every view request.

But I was wondering, would is this too much for my backend to handle (since it would have to talk to googles servers every time anybody views an image, which might be every few seconds for each user and I would be billed while the server waits for a response) or be too expensive, since I have to pay google on every request?  Or is there some other obvious problem with this?

I'm asking since I have only ever found recaptcha used for single form validation and never for traffic measurements, even though that seems like a pretty obvious use case.